# I am stuck in doing splitting

Tags: apex

What i want is if String myString='["Mobile","Fixed Site"]';
i want to put those values which are in " "  in a list. But i am unable to do so properly.
Please help.Thanks.

```
String myString='["Mobile","Fixed Site"]';
String NewString = myString.replaceAll('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ');
//system.debug('NewString ' +NewString);
String[] newString1=NewString.split(' ', 1);
    
System.debug('first '+ newString1[0]+' '+'second '+newString1[1]);
```

Comment: Hello Rajiv - Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. Could you please clarify the expected output of the code above? Are you expecting a string array on `newString1` with "Mobile" and "Fixed Site"?

Comment: Hi, I want newString1[0]=Mobile     and  newString1[1]=Fixed Site

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, what you have is a JSON list. Instead of trying to replace characters and split, you can simply deserialize.

```
String myString = ''; //your string here
List<String> strList = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(myString, List<String>.class);
system.debug(strList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JSON deserialization, then it will help to understand what exactly is happening with your code.

After your `replaceAll()`, your string becomes `'  Mobile   Fixed Site  '`.
That's 2 leading and 2 trailing whitespaces, and 3 whitespaces between your two values.

Since you have "Fixed Site", which has a space that you want to keep, using whitespace as your delimiter in `split()` is a poor choice. You could make it work (trim to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace, only split on 2 or more whitespaces), but that's certainly going about things the hard way (and pretty fragile).

It'd instead be much better to choose a better delimiter and not introduce extraneous whitespace. You already have a comma in your input, which can easily serve as a delimiter. The only thing you have to do is to get rid of the non-word characters.

If you can tolerate underscores in the output, the `\w` character class (`\\w` because we need to double up on backslashes in apex) is equivalent to `[A-Za-z_0-9]`. So to get rid of everything that isn't a word character *or the comma that you're trying to preserve*, the regex would look like `[^\\w, ]`. The extra space in the regex is required to preserve the space in "Fixed Site". If the second parameter of `replaceAll()` is `''` (the empty string), then the characters matching the regex are removed.

That leaves you with `'Mobile,Fixed Site'`. Split on the comma, and you have your list.